# using bash script to extract a number

Tags: linux, text-processing, scripting

I have a text file containing information that I want to extract:

```
PATTERN 1
bla bla bla.. XYSS$40$$$3 bla bla...    
bla bla bla..
bla bla bla.. GNDC$3$$$23 bla bla bla..
```

I want to extract `XYSS$40$$$3` and multiply 40 x 3 and display the result along with the line number on screen.

Same for `GNDC$3$$$23`.

```
PATTERN2
bla bla bla.. KKKK$4$60 bla bla bla..
bla bla bla..
bla bla bla.. PPPP$10$3 bla bla bla..
```

I want to extract `KKKK$4$60` and multiply 4 x 60 and display the result along with the line number on the screen.

Comment: Are those 4 the only patterns you can have in your file?

Comment: bash isn't much of a text processing tool; you just want something you can run from your bash command-line shell.

Comment: @PesaThe i could be anything having four upper case letter

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, you probably have Perl, so

```
$ cat input1 
PATTERN 1
bla bla bla.. XYSS$40$$$3 bla bla...    
bla bla bla..
bla bla bla.. GNDC$3$$$23 bla bla bla..

$ perl -ne 'while (/[A-Z]{4}\$+(\d+)\$+(\d+)/g) { 
    printf "line %3d: $1 * $2 = %d\n", $., $1*$2; }' < input1
line   2: 40 * 3 = 120
line   4: 3 * 23 = 69
```

The regex pattern matches four uppercase letters (`[A-Z]{4}`), then some dollar signs (`\$+`), followed by digits (`(\d+)`) and dollars and digits again. The parenthesis capture the numbers to `$1` and `$2`, and `$.` contains the current line number. Change the `printf` to taste.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`:

```
gawk 'match($0, /[A-Z]{4}\$+([0-9]+)\$+([0-9]+)/, nums) { 
   print "Line number: "NR", result: "nums[1]*nums[2] 
}' file
```

Comment: Thanka this works , can I get equivalent of it in python

Comment: @user143252 if you wanted python, you should've mentioned it in the question or use tags.